# how to make new checkbox in form partner

Tags: odoo

I want ask, please help me

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_instructor_form_view">
<field name="name">partner.instructor.name</field>
<field name="model">res.partner</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="supplier" position="after">
        <field name="instructor"/>
    </field>
</field>
```

this code works on openerp 603, but how to convert to OpenERP version 604 ?
because in 604 that's code doesn't work

Comment: There are no significant differences from 603 to 604. Can you post your error traceback?

Comment: there was no error, just not turn up anything

Answer (score 0):

it may isue of access right, and and use -u -d options to update the database so that you can get your view updated.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its always useful to use XPath while searching for a path in the XML but if you are simply giving the field definition then make sure to copy the whole field definition and then define the position attribute.
   Also if that also not works then try to do update all modules.
eg. openerp-server -u all -d

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have any instructor field in your model, please check such a field exist in your model. add a new field if there is none.